# Force variable replacement in PHP string

Tags: php

Is there any way to force a string to evaluate (as a double quoted string/heredoc would)?

For example is there some clean way of doing this:

```
<?php
$mystring = <<<'MS'
hello {$adjectives['first']} world
MS;

$adjectives = array('first'=>'beautiful');

// here I want to print 'hello beautiful world' 
// instead of 'hello {$adjectives['first']} world'
echo evaluate($mystring); // evaluate is not a real function
?>
```

Comment: Can you just define `$mySytring` after `$adjectives` has been defined?

Comment: @JuanMendes No, otherwise this would be trivial. I would use a heredoc or double quoted string instead. The point is I want a string evaluated at a later point in time.

Comment: That's my point, why don't you explain why you need it?

Comment: @JuanMendes It's necessary for code-reuse and readability purposes. The actual string I want evaluated is very very long and I don't want to put a heredoc everywhere I need it evaluated. The alternate method is of course, using php's include or require so the code doesn't get convoluted, but I was just wondering if there was a better way of doing that.

Comment: Instead of using heredoc, use a normal string with placeholders for `sprintf`?

Comment: @ɴᴀᴛʜ That's probably the neatest way. IDK why I didn't think of that. Thanks. =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) since you plan to use it only on strings you created your self. Don't ever use `eval` if the string (or the replacements) are outside your control.

```
$mystring = <<<'MS'
hello %s world
MS;

$adjectives = array('first'=>'beautiful');

eval('$parsed = ' . json_encode($mystring) . ';');
echo($parsed);
```

See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b1f6afc24efbc685f738dc1e7fd3668afdf5b7d0

As suggested by NATH, sprintf would do the job for you without the security implications of `eval`

```
$mystring = <<<'MS'
hello %s world
MS;

$adjectives = array('first' => 'beautiful');
echo sprintf($mystring, $adjectives['first']);
```

Comment: Please don't promote the use of this function without mentioning how potentially dangerous it can be without proper caution on the input.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise to avoid using `eval()`. I think it's dangerous, slow, and a bad practice in general. Using `vsprintf()` instead should do the trick for you.

```
// Use argument swapping (%1\$s instead of %s) to explicitly specify which
// position in the array represents each value. Useful if you're swapping out
// multiple values.
$mystring = <<<MS
hello %1\$s world
MS;

$adjectives = array('first'=>'beautiful');

echo vsprintf($mystring, $adjectives);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes and you nearly got it.

Look at this example for [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) @ php.net

```
<?php
$string = 'cup';
$name = 'coffee';
$str = 'This is a $string with my $name in it.';
echo $str. "\n";
eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
echo $str. "\n";
?>
```

Please note however, that using eval is dangerous and opens the possibility of all kind of attacks if not handled properly.

Maybe a better solution would be to use place holders of some kind.

```
$str = "This is a __first__ world";

$adjectives = array('first'=>'beautiful');

foreach ($adjectives as $k=>$v) {
   $str = preg_replace('/__'.$k.'__/', $v, $str); 
}

echo $str;
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if the string contains both quotes and double quotes You have to escape them http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/35fbe3827b0011ca88f6ec3c9763b55f4da68503

Comment: I don't like the idea of using eval. =\

Comment: Well its from php.net so...
Also ofc it does: $str = 'This is a \'$string\' with \\"my\\" $name in it.';
Works just fine.

Comment: @Torge did you click on my example?